# Is thread::get_id (C++11) lock free?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I would like to **test the thread calling different functions** of one of my classes. I have a critical time thread, and I don't want anyone to call a function that may call `new` to be called from that thread. However, as the 2 functions are public, I can't enforce it by the language.

My idea is **to test the thread id**. Assuming that I can ensure that the call initializing the thread id is in the right thread, I would just have to call `thread::get_id()` in other calls and compare to the thread id I saved.

The problem is that **I also want to test in the critical thread this ID but I can not lock in that thread.**

Therefore my question is: Is `thread::get_id()` lock free (and what could be the worst time of execution)?

Comment: You could use `thread_local` to store a `bool` that indicates whether that thread can use `new` or not.

Comment: @DyP: I guess your TLS / `bool` idea is probably the best workaround, it would be too much of a headache otherwise to guarantee something across all possible implementations.

Comment: @syam IIRC the Standard doesn't guarantee anything about locking besides the sequence of some operations between different threads. I.e. I don't think there's a **guarantee** that TLS won't lock, either.

Comment: I didn't know that thread_local was already supported by vs2012

Comment: @DyP: ah right, so back to square one...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Standard gives no guarantee either way as to whether `thread::get_id()` and `std::this_thread::get_id()` are lock-free or not, or even concerning their complexity.

I'm afraid the answer to your question is implementation-specific, depending on your particular Standard library and underlying threads library.

Comment: Yeah I was looking for some hard info on this. I can't think of a good reason why that call would require locking. Constructors and copy constructors can set the id once and leave it at that.

Comment: I can't think of no good reason either. Unfortunately, since the standard provides no guarantee, guesses are useless.

Comment: Both libc++ and libstdc++ just implement that by storing the `pthread_t` as the ID, so no locking is required for these 2 particular implementations.

Comment: @KennyTM: good to know. So I guess that `std::this_thread::get_id()` maps to `pthread_self()`, but then how is this system call implemented under the hood? One would also need to dig in his particular `pthreads` implementation to be sure.

Comment: Hi so I'm working on win and macosX with the libc++ and msvc library. so I guess that for this there is no guaranty but it should be ok. Is there any trait that could give this information ?

Comment: @dzada: "*Is there any trait?*" => Not that I'm aware of.